# Unable to Automatically display Haar Cascade Classifier Methods in V.S. Code in OpenCV Project

Tags: python, opencv, visual-studio-code

I have imported the haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml (named haar_face.xml) file in V.S Code for my OpenCV Project. I have named declared a haar cascade classifier as follows:-

```
haar_cascade = cv.CascadeClassifier('haar_face.xml')

faces_rect = haar_cascade.detectMultiScale()
```

But, V.S. Code doesn't automatically display the detectMultiScale() method after I write haar_cascade. in faces_rect variable. Any suggestions on how can I resolve this issue? Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Did you select the python interpreter correctly for VSCODE environment? And is your linter suggesting other library functions for opencv?

Comment: @Shafi Thanks for the reply! The others are working fine in OpenCV in VS. Code. I am onkly having the problem with haar cascade classifier!

Comment: so I checked on and yes you are correct, it does work for other methods, even the other cv2 methods, but doesn't work on this. now, I may not be correct but my guess is the CascadeClassifier() method returns a class object that is not encoded int the python API rather directly thrown from the compiled C/C++ shared object. You can check this by trying to inspect the cv2.CascadeClassifier() method.  Therefore pylint cannot suggest you the method. But python interpreter can run the code since it has the shared object referred in the Python API and the internal call happens

Comment: in the compiled shared object.